# Loading VirtualBox with Windows 10 Enterprise results in a plaid screen and nothing else

Tags: windows-10, virtualbox, iso-image

I'm trying to load Windows 10 enterprise in VirtualBox and when I start the VM I get a screen that's just a field of green and orange plaid and nothing else. Any idea where this went wrong? Would an error in the download of the .iso file produce this result? It looks like this:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this thread, it looks the same with some good answers:

[Virtualbox Windows 10 install boots into checkered screen](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1114569/virtualbox-windows-10-install-boots-into-checkered-screen)

Comment: Great suggestions. For me the solution was to upgrade to the latest version of VirtualBox and redownload the iso file.